# Calculating temporary coordinate if distance exceeds 100

Tags: c#, math

I have a problem with coding a function that will do the following:

Function will take 2 sets of coordinates (x,y,z). First set is starting point and second one is end point.
Now first i will have to determine distance between those two points. If distance will be greater than lets say 100 then i will have to calculate a temporary point. I will then calculate distance between first set of coordinates and this temporary point. Please check illustration below  i am sure things will be much more understandable.

Function that calculates new point between points A,B:

```
x = (x1+x2/2) 
y = (y1+y2/2)
z = (z1+z2/2)
```

Function that calculates distance is:

```
public float DistanceTo(float x, float y, float z, float x2, float y2, float z2)
        {
            float a = x - x2;
            float b = y - y2;
            float c = z - z2;

            return Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b + c * c);

        }
```

Link to illustration:

[image]

Perhaps my approach will be CPU heavy and perhaps slow (?) but currently i am out of ideas how to approach the problem.

Basically i need a function that will go from A to B in increments if (distance < 100).

Thank you for reading and thanks for any solution posted!

PS please dont make fun of my paint skills :)

Comment: simply calculate the points along the line

Comment: Question is how do i do that? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Why are you mixing float, double and int?

Comment: Disregard data types or typos in syntax that please.

Comment: well you have two poitns on the line, so you can infer its equation and then calculate however many points on the line between whatever bound you want.

Comment: I think you mean `x = ( (x1+x2)/2 )` and similarly for the others and not `x = (x1+x2/2) `. You do want to get the mid point _C_ right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it recursively

create a Point struct that represent a point in R3, with 2 utility methods to calculate the distance and midpoint.

```
struct Point
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    public double Distance(Point b)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b.x - this.x, 2) +
                         Math.Pow(b.y - this.y, 2) +
                         Math.Pow(b.z - this.z, 2));
    }

    public  Point MidPoint(Point b)
    {
        return new Point()
        {
            x = (this.x + b.x) / 2,
            y = (this.y + b.y) / 2,
            z = (this.z + b.z) / 2
        };
    }
}
```

and write a simple recursive function that will calculate the distance and call itself recursively until the distance between point a and the temp point is less than maxSegmentLength which is 100 in your case:

```
public static Point GetPoint(Point a, Point b, double maxSegmentLength)
    {
        var distance = a.Distance(b);
        if (distance < maxSegmentLength)
            return b;
        else
            return GetPoint(a, a.MidPoint(b),maxSegmentLength);
    }
```

Or more efficiently with vectors:

```
struct Vector
    {
        public double Vx;
        public double Vy;
        public double Vz;
        public double R;
        public Vector(Point a,Point b)
        {
            R = a.Distance(b);
            Vx = (b.x - a.x)/R;
            Vy = (b.y - a.y)/R;
            Vz = (b.z - a.z)/R;
        }

    }


public static Point GetPoint(Point a, Point b,double maxSegmentLength)
        {
            var Vab = new Vector(a, b);
            var dAC = Vab.R;
            while (dAC > maxSegmentLength) { dAC /= 2; } //or replace this line and the one above it with var dAC=Math.Pow(0.5,(int)(-(Math.Log(maxSegmentLength / Vab.R) / Math.Log(2))) + 1)*Vab.R;
            return new Point() {
                x = a.x + Vab.Vx * dAC ,
                y = a.y + Vab.Vy * dAC ,
                z = a.z + Vab.Vz * dAC 
            };
        }
```

Comment: not sure your maths is quite right, shouldnt it be x= a.x + (a.x-b.x)/2?

Comment: @Ewan: You probably mean `a.x +(b.x-a.x)/2` (consider the case of a.x=150 and b.x = 0. Clearly you want your new x to be 75. With your calculation it will be 225 (because your vector a-b is going from b to a so you should either add it to b or reverse it). The formula I gave is then equivalent to the one in the answer, just rearranged a bit. One advantage of this format is that you can use it to parameterize the line between a and b by defining it as `a.x+t(b.x-a.x)`. For t from 0 to 1 will give points on the line joining the two allowing you to find multiple points more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the distance `d` from `(xb,yb,zb)` (begin) to `(xe,ye,ze)` (end). Compute the number of parts `N=(int)((d-1)/100)+1`. Compute

```
xk = xb + (k*(xe-xb))/N
yk = yb + (k*(ye-yb))/N
zk = zb + (k*(ze-zb))/N
```

for `k=1,...,N-1` to get equally spaced points on the segment with a distance not surpassing `100`.

Answer (score 0):

If the point is always at a midpoint then its distance is always half of the original

```
public double Calc(Point A, Point B)
{
    double d = Distance(A,B);
    while(d>100)
    {
       d/=2;
    }
    return d;
}
```